# Idiomatic way of documenting a Golang program, consisting of one main.go file

Tags: go, documentation, idioms, godoc

I wrote a Go tool which reads files and produces output based on the input. It consists of one main.go file. Where do I document what the tool does, in order to make use of godoc (or just be idiomatic)?

```
// Should I explain it here?
package main

// Or here?
func main() {
    // code!
}

// Or somewhere else?
```

Comment: You may want to look at the following article about it https://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code . It perfectly explains idiomatic way of preparing Godoc

Comment: Yeah, I read it, but it's about packages and exported functions only. Here I have the main package and no exported functions.

Comment: Then most probably you have also read that article https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc . Basically when you want to look at the doc of this package/function, you are going to run "godoc main" like you do on any other package, right? So since it is also a package, all idiomatic ways are also valid for that too.

Comment: godoc is intended to document Go library APIs; since you can't import main, there's nothing in a main package worth documenting from that standpoint. If you want to document what the tool does, README.md or the like is probably the better and more idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To document a command for godoc or pkg.go.dev, write the command documentation in the package comment.

```
// Command foo does bar.
package main

func main() {
   // code!
}
```

See the [comment in stringer.go](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/ac1e4b1998e6a311e006d9629b9283295dee36a3/cmd/stringer/stringer.go#L5-L59) and [the stringer documentation](http://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer) for an example.

By default, godoc and pkg.go.dev hide all other doc comments in a package with the name "main".

Comment: As an example you can look at
https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/cmd/stringer/stringer.go
and try to run 'godoc cmd/stringer'